# Interacting with files in Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I've got a GCP pipeline which contains several containers on Cloud Run, each of which requires a given type of input (XML, PDF etc...). A couple cloud functions written in Python help orchestrate the workflow.

These inputs are stored in Cloud Storage, and I can retrieve them as binary. However, given the XML or PDF object is in a blob representation, the blob cannot directly serve as inputs to my containers.

I could convert the blob to XML or PDF, then store the file in the cloud function temp directory and then pass them to the relevant containers. I'd however like to avoid saving the file, and pass the blob to the container with the minimum amount of intermediary steps.

What would be the most efficient way?

Comment: You say the files are already in GCS, so why do you need to "covert" and "upload"?

Comment: Yes, by uploading I meant pass them to the next container. I save the intermediary outputs of the pipelines in GCS, where they can be picked up for the next step

Comment: Not sure I understand "pass", but you can call [`Blob.download_to_filename`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_download_to_filename) and `upload_from_filename`

Comment: Cheers, I'd be looking for a way to avoid entirely having to save the file to the directory (whether blob or any other format). Ideally I'd be able to stream the object as input into the containers which take PDF or XML as input.

Comment: You can use a `BlobReader` and call `read(N)` to download in chunks of the files... But, you're going to have to download the full file to actually process anything because XML has closing tags, for example, so you need all the content, and I assume PDFs are similar. If you had line-delimited CSV files, then that would be different

Comment: Thanks, so all in all no way to avoid saving the input file in the cloud functions temp dir ? How would I best go about it if the files are hundreds of MBs ?

Comment: Not sure file size is really relevant other than your functions will obviously take longer for larger files. Other options could be to use DataProc/DataFlow to asynchronously process large files.

Comment: Why do the services directly download the file from Cloud Storage instead of reading it from Cloud Functions and stream the content to the container. You seem stuck somewhere where you shouldn't be.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere That's exactly what I'd like to do. How would I do that - without modifying the containers which only accept XML or PDF files ? I tried a couple Byte or String IO ideas but none worked

Comment: There are multiple solutions in other languages, but I don't see any solution in Python (and I'm not a python expert/fan). If you can write your code in node or java, or Go, it should be possible. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-stream-file-download

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#stream_a_download) does show `BytesIO` Python solution using `download_to_file` function that I linked above